# How to make Scrollview automatically scroll to the bottom when RadioButton is clicked

Tags: android, kotlin

**How to make Scrollview automatically scroll to the  bottom when RadioButton is clicked**
May I know How to make the Scroll view automatically scroll down to the next_button when any of the Radio Button is clicked ,
**in the same time** I need to call "setMeal() method from the ViewModel when the  Radio Button is clicked.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".ui.MainMeal">

<data>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.example.mymeal.model.OrderViewModel" />
    
    <variable
        name="mainMeal"
        type="com.example.mymeal.ui.MainMeal" />
 </data>

 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:paddingEnd="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp">

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/divider"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/main_meal_options"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/royal_lobster"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text='@{viewModel.menuItems["royal butter lobster"].name}'
                    android:onClick='@{() -> viewModel.setMeal("royal butter lobster")}'
                    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody1"
                    tools:text="Royal Butter Lobster" />

                <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                    android:id="@+id/royal_lobster_image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="194dp"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/cut_corner"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/royal_butter_lobster" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/royal_lobster_description"
                    style="@style/Widget.MenuItem.TextView.Info"
                    android:text='@{viewModel.menuItems["royal butter lobster"].description}'
                    tools:text="Entree 3 description" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/royal_lobster_price"
                    style="@style/Widget.MenuItem.TextView.Info"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:text='@{viewModel.menuItems["royal butter 
 lobster"].getFormattedPrice()}'
                    tools:text="$0.00" />

                <View
                    style="@style/Widget.MyMeal.Divider"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/royal_lobster_description" />


                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/kebbeh"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text='@{viewModel.menuItems["kebbeh"].name}'
                    android:onClick='@{() -> viewModel.setMeal("kebbeh")}'
                    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody1"
                    tools:text="Kebbeh" />

                <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                    android:id="@+id/kebbeh_image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="194dp"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/cut_corner"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/kebbeh" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/kebbeh_description"
                    style="@style/Widget.MenuItem.TextView.Info"
                    android:text='@{viewModel.menuItems["kebbeh"].description}'
                    tools:text="Entree 4 description" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/kebbeh_price"
                    style="@style/Widget.MenuItem.TextView.Info"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:text='@{viewModel.menuItems["kebbeh"].getFormattedPrice()}'
                    tools:text="$0.00" />

                <View
                    style="@style/Widget.MyMeal.Divider"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/kebbeh_description" />


                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/shish_tawook"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text='@{viewModel.menuItems["shish tawook"].name}'
                    android:onClick='@{() -> viewModel.setMeal("shish tawook")}'
                    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody1"
                    tools:text="Shish Tawook" />

                <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                    android:id="@+id/shish_tawook_image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="194dp"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/cut_corner"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/shish_tawook" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/shish_tawook_description"
                    style="@style/Widget.MenuItem.TextView.Info"
                    android:text='@{viewModel.menuItems["shish tawook"].description}'
                    tools:text="Entree 4 description" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/shish_tawook_price"
                    style="@style/Widget.MenuItem.TextView.Info"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:text='@{viewModel.menuItems["shish tawook"].getFormattedPrice()}'
                    tools:text="$0.00" />


            </RadioGroup>
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider"
            style="@style/Widget.MyMeal.Divider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cardView" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subtotal"
            style="@style/Widget.MyMeal.TextView.Subtotal"
            android:text='@{@string/subtotal(viewModel.subtotal)}'
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/divider"
            tools:text="Subtotal $5.00" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next_button"
            style="@style/Widget.Order.Button.Next"
            android:onClick="@{()-> mainMeal.goToNextFragment()}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/cancel_button"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/subtotal" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>

</layout>
```

This is the fragment class file

```
package com.example.mymeal.ui




class MainMeal : Fragment() {

// Binding object instance corresponding to the fragment_main_meal.xml layout.
private var _binding: FragmentMainMealBinding? = null

private val binding get() = _binding!!

//Get instance of OrderViewModel
private val sharedViewModel: OrderViewModel by activityViewModels()

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    _binding = FragmentMainMealBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
    binding.viewModel = sharedViewModel
    binding.mainMeal = this
}

//Navigate to the salad menu fragment
fun goToNextFragment() {
    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_mainMeal_to_saladMenu)
}

//Cancel the order
private fun cancelOrder() {
    //Reset the values
    sharedViewModel.resetOrder()
    //Navigate back to the start fragment
    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_mainMeal_to_startFragment)
}

private fun doNothing() {
    return
}

//confirmation before cancel the order
fun showDialog() {
    MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(requireContext()).setMessage(getString(R.string.cancel_order))
        .setCancelable(true)
        .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.yes)) { _, _ -> cancelOrder() }
        .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.no)) { _, _ -> doNothing() }.show()
}

/**
Clear out the binding object when the view hierarchy associated with the fragment
 is being removed
*/
override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code when the radio button is checked

```
scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks , but I'm using kotlin not java , in another hand I can't use the views inside the viewModel class

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
    fun scrollToViewBottom(scrollView: ScrollView, childView: View) {
    val delay: Long = 500 //delay to let finish with possible modifications to ScrollView
    scrollView.postDelayed({ scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, childView.bottom) }, delay)
}
```

**Call the function:**

```
    radioButton.setOnClickListener {
        if (radioButton.isChecked) {
            println("checked")
            scrollToViewBottom(ScrollViewExplore, Mypage)
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks ,but still can't work